# How do you download node.js on mac without admin

Tags: node.js, macos, npm

I'm On my school mac learning how to program a game and everyone is using node.js and every place I look I can't find how to download node.js without admin.

Comment: Follow this [guide](http://theshravan.net/blog/how-to-use-node-and-npm-without-installation-or-admin-rights/).

Comment: I tried this one before but I don't understand step 4. Is step 4 used on mac cause I don't see the computer or properties when I right click?

Comment: Do you need Xcode because I don't have and can't get?

Answer (score 1):

You can install it using a version manager. This doesn't usually require admin rights.

My Node version manager of choice is [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm).

The quick install is:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash
```

or:

```
wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash
```

But I'd encourage you to read the more in-depth instructions on the project's home page.

Once the version manager is installed, you can list available Node versions using:

```
nvm ls-remote
```

You can then install any version of Node that you desire using:

```
nvm install <version number>
```

For example, to install the latest LTS version:

```
nvm install --lts
```

But this is just a very brief overview of its functionality. I'd advise you to take a look the project's [README](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/blob/master/README.md) to find out what else it can do.

Comment: This didn't work said I need Xcode tried to get Xcode but it didn't work help?

Comment: Shame. I don't have a Mac, so can't help further. Sorry.

Comment: Do you know anyone that might know how?

Comment: I don't. Sorry. It is somewhat of an unusual request, TBH.

Comment: Any other ways you can think of for me to "npm" without node.js?

Comment: I'M afraid not. npm is an app written entirely in JavaScript and depends very heavily on Node.js.

Comment: Dunno. I would guess not, but why not just try it if you are curious.

Answer (score 1):

Still requires Xcode but here are some more details:

1. Install Xcode
2. Run Xcode and agree
3. Download Xcode command line tools
4. Make sure git runs via the command line (nvm uses git, which is installed by Xcode)
5. > touch ~/.zshrc (if you don’t have this file, also used by nvm)
6. > curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.36.0/install.sh | bash
7. Close and reopen the terminal (nvm was just added to the path)
8. > nvm install --lts